# Looking for a one click method to recompile GWT client code by using the codeserver?

Tags: gwt, gwt-compiler, gwt-super-dev-mode

I have a single module GWT project.  The compilation with codeserver works fine.

However, I find the procedure of recompiling my client code with the codeserver unnecessarily cumbersome.  Do I really have to click on three buttons for one recompilation?

- 1st button: "Dev Mode On"
- 2nd button: "compile"
- 3rd button: "OK" button of the message dialog "GWT module 'mywebapp' may need to be (re)compiled"

Is there any chance to automate this procedure so that I have to perform only one click or one keyboard shortcut?

#### Edit 2014-04-19:

I start the webserver via `mvn gwt:run` and the codeserver via `mvn gwt:run-codeserver`.

Answer (score 1):

Just one button to click, and you are already clicking it:

> 2nd button: "compile"

It turns out the Compile button in the Dev Mode On screen is another bookmarklet - you just need to stick that near Dev Mode On and Off.

---

> 3rd button: "OK" button of the message dialog "GWT module 'mywebapp' may need to be (re)compiled"

This should not show up at all. If it is, you are also running regular dev mode while super dev mode is going - regular dev mode deletes the contents of your compiled code, which is why you are getting this other message.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the "compile" button.  It works great.  But how do you start the webapp without running dev mode?  If I put the webapp into tomcat, the codeserver does not recognize the GWT module anymore.

Comment: It should recognize it, even if running in a qa or production server off of your laptop. If it doesn't that suggests that maybe you didn't build with the dev mode flags in your .gwt.xml file.